# Making my MVC Async controller methods asynchronous so they can process at the same time

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following async code:

```
public class AsynchronousController : AsyncController
{
    public ActionResult IndexSynchronous(string city)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> AsyncTest(string call1, string call2)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The goal is that I can simply open IndexSynchronous while AsyncTest is processing, but this way it does not work. I verified this by first calling Asynctest and then calling IndexSynchronous, which is still waiting for the other action.

Could anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Because you are blocking AsyncTest method synchronously. use delay like `await Task.Delay(10000);`

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan I added this, but it is still processing processing synchronous (I also added it to the orginal question)

Comment: Why are you using `AsyncController`?

Comment: @CodeCaster Because I want the code to run async? I have never worked with asynchronous code before, but I came across this when looking async implementations for MVC

Comment: This won't work because, using even if you use `await`, this will only make your current thread to wait. But there are multiple worker threads available for the application in IIS thread pool. So, any other available thread will pick your next request.

Comment: Disregarding the fact `AsyncController` is only for backwards compatibility and has been dropped,***PRO TIP*** if you claim something is not working, you need to go out of your way and show how you are coming to this conclusion (how you are proving this to your self). As there is always a chance your assumptions are wrong

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You don't need any asynchronous calls, ASP.NET was able to handle calls in parallel just fine before. I don't understand your requirements, and you did not post the code that is actually run to test your requirements. There is nothing to answer here without an actual question.

Comment: So, do you use sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async - Await is not about parallel programming. It is meant to avoid useless CPU processing while waiting for IO operations.

When you do:

```
string fileContent = await GetFileContent();
```

you're just telling the current thread to stop its execution until it receives an interupt (IO operation completed).
Now tasks come in: when a thread which is executing a tasks *awaits* an IO operation to continue it can start executing another task while its waiting.

The degree of parallelism of a process is given by the number of thread of the threadpool that is using. Each thread than executes tasks. When a thread calls awaits stop the execution of the current task and starts executing another one.

**Async - Await** is about improving performance by avoiding thread to use CPU while waiting for IO operation

To answer your question, even in old ASP.NET web applications without async controllers you are able to process different requests (and so different controller actions) at the same time. You don't have to do anything to reach this.

Comment: '*It is meant to avoid useless CPU processing while waiting for IO operations*" I would double check this fact.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/ :)